# What is the best notebook to run Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04

If I need a new notebook today and I go shopping, which notebook should I buy?

I mean: a notebook that supports Ubuntu 13.04 without any issue.

It hasn't to be the most powerful notebook. It must be Ubuntu 13.04 friendly.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are not allowed on askubuntu ;) http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also if you do a fresh install today, it would be more logical to install 14.04 rather than 13.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at laptops that come with Ubuntu pre-installed, they are meant to be running Ubuntu out-of-the-box without any issue:

- [System 76](https://www.system76.com/)
- [Dell with Ubuntu](http://partners.ubuntu.com/dell)

There are others that offer Ubuntu pre installed, such as [Think Penguim](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/) and [ZaReason](http://zareason.com/shop/Laptops/).

Although you'd better take a look at [Certified Hardware by Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/), the Desktop section (Yes, it also includes laptops) is a full list of laptops that are meant to run perfectly with Ubuntu.